# Can I use exec and upload during the same SSH session?

Tags: ruby, ssh, scp

I need to perform several operations during an ssh session. At the moment I am using `SSH.start` and `SCP.start` for the remote operations and uploads respectively. This is an example:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, options) do |session|
  output = session.exec!(cmd)
end   

Net::SCP.start(host, user, options) do |scp|
  scp.upload!(src, dst, :recursive => true)
  scp.upload!(src1, dst1, :recursive => true)
end

Net::SSH.start(host, user, options) do |session|
  output = session.exec!(cmd)
end
```

The problem is that for every operation the SSH connection needs to be re-established and this is affecting the overall performance.

Is there a way to open a session and then perform all the required operations such as commands, uploads and downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH protocol allows multiple channels per connection. So technically it is possible.

I do not know Ruby net-ssh implementation, but from it's API it seems to support this.

The [constructor of `Net::SCP` class](http://net-ssh.github.io/scp/v1/api/classes/Net/SCP.html#M000008) takes an exiting SSH session.

```
# Creates a new Net::SCP session on top of the given Net::SSH +session+
# object.
def initialize(session)
```

So pass your existing `Net::SSH` instance to the `Net::SCP` constructor, instead of starting a new session using `.start` method.